# Kendo dropdownlist set selected item with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

in angularjs with kendo ui dropdownlist, how can i set the selected item?

If i have this control:

```
<select name="product" kendo-drop-down-list style="width: 200px" k-options="customOptions" ng-model="newProduct.name"></select>
```

in the angularjs controller:

```
$scope.newProduct.icon
```

has the index of the item selected (and it's ok). But how can i set the item?

Comment: can you please create a plunkr/fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the property you want in a k-data-text-field and the ng-model to hold the entire object, this way just changing that object should work.

```
<select name="product" kendo-drop-down-list style="width: 200px" k-options="customOptions" ng-model="newProduct" k-data-text-field="'name'"></select>
```